# Orden de preferencia en una expresión

Tags: java

Tengo esta expresión:

```
  int a = 2;
  boolean res = false;
  res = a++ == 2 || --a == 2 && --a == 2;
```

Después de ejecutarse el valor de *a*, toma el valor de 3. No consigo ver por qué termina valiendo 3.

Yo lo que veo que primero hace el `2 == 2` que es true, con lo que la segunda expresión del `||` no la hace y a toma el valor de 3, pero luego hace el `--a` del `&&` con lo que valdría 2 finalmente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda exactamente, qué por qué `a` termina valiendo `3`? Porque inicialmente vale `2` y aquí le sumas `1`: **`a++`**

Comment: Se dice [*precedencia* de operadores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

A eso se le llama "cortocircuito".

En tu caso tienes una expresión simplificada así:

`true || expresion`

Como la primera parte de la expresión es verdadera entonces la segunda no se ejecuta, de ahí el nombre "cortocircuito". La mayoría de lenguajes de alto nivel modernos lo soportan.